# Double click for desktop view and single tap for phone

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I want to create 2 gestures for my application. Usually, I should be able to double click on a card to open it in desktop view. But when the dimension is for a phone, only a single tap should do the job. How should I proceed with it?
The code below is for the desktop view.

```
        <Grid item xs={2} key={keyId}>
            <Card xs={12}}}
                onDoubleClick={() => { addProject(projname) }}>
        </Grid>
```

Any kind of help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can make another `<Card />` component with `onClick` and set its display to `none` for mobile dimensions:

```
<Grid item xs={2} key={keyId}>
  <Card sx={{ display: {xs: "none", md: "block"} }} xs={12}
  onDoubleClick={() => { addProject(projname) }}>
    ...
  </Card>
  <Card sx={{ display: {xs: "block", md: "none"} }} onClick={() => {addProject(projname)}}
    ...
  </Card>
</Grid>
```